# PHPUnit autocomplete in PhpStorm doesn't work

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I cant autocomplete PHPUnit assert methods in PhpStorm 2016.3.2

When I type `$this->ass` there is no autocomplete. If I just type `ass` I can the whole list and when I autocomplete `assertEquals` for example I get self::assertEquals()

With CTRL + Click he brings the PHPUnit class up with all the methods -- so PhpStorm finds PHPUnit.

I don't quite get whats the problem here. Has anybody got an idea?

Comment: That is correct `assertEquals` is a static method and should not really be called via `$this->` way. Such behaviour is new for PhpStorm 2016.3 (or 2016.2) -- it was [requested by users](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9403). You may just press `Ctrl+Space` one more time and IDE will list all possible options, even static methods for `$this->`. At the same time -- it should work for PHPUnit methods as per https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32530

Comment: @LazyOne I tried that with CTRL + space -- but no luck with that.

Comment: Try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE then. It works just fine here in 2016.3.2 version.

Comment: @LazyOne Did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is rather correct: `assertEquals` is a static method and should not really be called via `$this->` way. Such behaviour is new for PhpStorm 2016.3 (or 2016.2) -- [it was requested by IDE users](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9403).

You may just press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> one more time and IDE will list all possible options, even static methods for `$this->`.

---

At the same time -- it should work for PHPUnit methods (as per [WI-32530](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32530) ticket).

If it does not -- try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE then -- it works just fine here (as seen on screenshot below):

[image]